# How to dump physical memory on OS X?

Tags: macos

With root permissions, how do I dump the physical memory on a OSX machine? Looking for an equivalent to Linux's /dev/mem or /dev/kmem. I read about sleepimage, but not sure how to uncompress it (it's only 1GB on my Mac with 16GB memory)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Mac OS X Internals](http://www.osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter8/kma/)  book, Apple removed the `/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem` devices from the system, so it is not possible to access these special devices.

As for the workaround, you need to implement your own kernel extension implementing your own memory device. For example, check the [`comex/Kmem` project](https://github.com/comex/Kmem).

According to this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122672/22781), you can also enable it using the following boot argument:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kmem=1"
```

then reboot.

See also: [How to access /dev/mem in OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/114319/22781)